# "java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable" in Service Android

Tags: android, service

My problem is:

I am developing an android application with a service. This service uses the Internet to consume a webservice. It works perfect, but if I leave the phone locked a long time, the following error occurs in the

```
log: "java.net.SocketException: Network unreachable".
```

The application works again perfect to unlock the phone.

I guess after some time to save battery disables internet until you activate the phone again.

Any solution?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not believe. There is a very hidden option where I can not turn off the wifi when the phone is locked. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Android does deactivate the WiFi after a while to save battery. I think this can be changed in the phone settings, but AFAIK there's no way to do it from your app.

Comment: the tip that i can give is by adding a check of the network state before consuming the webservice, as you have nothing to do if the device or the user deactivate wifi or other internet sources (3G/4G)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need the service to work continuously and wifi... In the phone galaxy note perfect run, but in the gt-i5500 does not work. check the settings but nowhere says turn off or disconnect the wifi.

Comment: I can not believe. There is a very hidden option where I can not turn off the wifi when the phone is locked. Sorry for your time and thank you for your help.